# CodeIgniter: Multiple files upload with multiple inputs

Tags: file, codeigniter, input, upload

Hello this is not really a question but rather an answer. I spend countless hours trying to find a simple solution to this problem here on Stack Overflow but couldn't.. Most answers were about uploading multiple files with a single input and people most of the time just recommend the use of the multi upload library from the Git. Well, for those who are actually trying to LEARN like me, this is a solution I've finally found on the net.

This is what the view look like: upload_form.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload');  ?>
<p>
    <?php echo form_label('File 1', 'userfile') ?>
    <?php echo form_upload('userfile') ?>
</p>
<p>
    <?php echo form_label('File 2', 'userfile1') ?>
    <?php echo form_upload('userfile1') ?>
</p>
<p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Upload them files!') ?></p>
<?php form_close() ?>
```

And the controller: upload.php

```
function index()
{
    // Has the form been posted?
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // Load the library - no config specified here
        $this->load->library('upload');

        // Check if there was a file uploaded - there are other ways to
        // check this such as checking the 'error' for the file - if error
        // is 0, you are good to code
        if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
        {
            // Specify configuration for File 1
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';       

            // Initialize config for File 1
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            // Upload file 1
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
            }
            else
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }

        }

        // Do we have a second file?
        if (!empty($_FILES['userfile1']['name']))
        {
            // Config for File 2 - can be completely different to file 1's config
            // or if you want to stick with config for file 1, do nothing!
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/dir2/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            // Initialize the new config
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            // Upload the second file
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
            }
            else
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view("upload_form");
    }
}
```

Voila!!!
Here is the original link to the tutorial: http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/08/upload-multiple-files-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score -1):

You can use code i found:

You have to create new library at application/libraries called MY_Upload.php
Here's the code for library: http://www.beetxt.com/hG2/

Copyrights goes to whoever made this

Controller function:

```
public function gallery()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile[]', 'bilde', '');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {

         //Configure upload.
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
            "upload_path"   => './img/gallery/',
            "allowed_types" => 'gif|jpg|png',
            "max_size"  => '9216',
            "max_width"  => '15360',
            "max_height" => '8640',
            "encrypt_name" => TRUE
        ));

    //Perform upload.
        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("userfile")){
            $imageData = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();

            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            foreach($imageData as $item) {
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = './img/gallery/' . $item['file_name'];
                $config['new_image'] = './img/gallery/thumb/' . $item['file_name'];
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 100;
                $config['height'] = 100;
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
                if( ! $this->image_lib->resize() )
                {
                    die($this->image_lib->display_errors());
                }
                $this->admin_model->insertGallery($item['file_name'], $item['raw_name']."_thumb".$item['file_ext']);
            }

        }
    }

    $data['page'] = "gallery";
    $data['pictures'] = $this->admin_model->getGallery();

    $this->load->view('admin_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin_gallery', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin_footer');

}
```